# What is the difference between MSTest.TestAdapter vs MSTest.TestFramework and when do I need which one?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

What is actualy the difference between `MSTest.TestAdapter` vs `MSTest.TestFramework` and when do I need which one?

In the NuGet descriptions you can read:

**MSTest.TestAdapter**

> The adapter to discover and execute MSTest Framework based tests.

**MSTest.TestFramework**

> This is MSTest V2, the evolution of Microsoft's Test Framework. + To discover and execute tests install MSTest.TestAdapter.

---

Well, not very helpful and I always install both because I'm never sure which one I should take. Strangely that in one of my test projects I only have the `MSTest.TestFramework` (I guess by accident) and ReSharper still can discover tests.

My questions about these packages are:

- Do you really always need to install both of them?
- Why does it work even without the `TestAdapter`?
- What can I do with the `TestFramework`? When would I need this one?

---

The project page on GitHub doesn't help much either. The only link

> You can read more about MSTest V2 [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/02/25/mstest-v2-now-and-ahead/).

navigates to a page that only says how great and open-source it is but nothing specific about either of the packages.

Comment: `What can I do with the TestFramework? When would I need this one?` Too broad and would require you to read the documentation provided by the developers.

Comment: @Nkosi oh, is there such a documentation? Do you mean [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting?view=mstest-net-1.1.17) It's where the github page points to and it looks like the ordinary assert documenation. Why is it too broad? A few words would be enough, currently I don't have the slightest idea what it is for.

Comment: [Unit Testing in .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/)

Comment: So in general a test framework is one used to create your tests while adaptors discover and exercise discovered tests. There are multiple frameworks and adaptors and you use the one of your choosing.

Comment: @Nkosi I think I might've found what I was looking for, there was a link on that page you named that points to [vstest-docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs) - still wondering why this link isn't nowhere to find on the projec's github page.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So Visual Studio uses a framework called Visual Studio Test Platform to load test adapters,

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest

To discover or execute test cases, VSTest would call the test adapters based on your project configuration. (That's why NUnit/xUnit/MSTest all ask you to install a test adapter NuGet package to your unit testing projects). So MSTest.TestAdapter exists for that purposes.

MSTest.TestFramework itself implements the testing frameworks and its contracts. So you need to add a NuGet reference of it in order to write unit test cases and have them compiled. Only compiled projects along with the test adapter can then be consumed by Visual Studio.

So the final answer to your question would be "you usually need both".

The other answer from @Nkosi of course can be right if you don't ever plan to use Visual Studio. MSTest has its own command line runner, which can run your unit test project without the test adapter.

Answer (score 6):

> Do you really always need to install both of them?

**No.** Why? *(See below)*

> Why does it work even without the TestAdapter?

There are other adapters/runners out there that can recognize MSTest framework and that can also discover and run MSTest Framework tests.

> What can I do with the TestFramework?

So in general a test framework is one used to create/author your tests while adapters/runners discover and exercise discovered tests.

> When would I need this one?

There are multiple frameworks and adapters/runners and you use the one of your choosing.

Answer (score 5):

MsTest.TestFramework contains the core framework which includes Attributes and Asserts. MsTest.TestAdapter allows us to discover the MsTest based tests and execute them. For example, identifying methods attributed with [TestMethod] and executing them.